# MPI or Asio for wide-area plugin-based message passing

Tags: c++, boost, boost-asio, mpi, distributed-system

I'm writing a distributed system wherein each node interfaces with local applications via some RESTful API, supports extensions and runtime customization, etc. It's a bit like an [Enterprise Service Bus](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Enterprise_service_bus) over the wide area, but with a lot else going on which is not related to the question at hand.

I've read a little about both MPI and Asio - originally I was set on Asio, but then I found MPI, and now  again I'm thinking Asio is the better solution for me. MPI seems to provide a lot I don't need and a higher level of abstraction than I want - for example, I only need point-to-point communication, and it is important to me to be in control of when and what data is transmitted. (e.g. I have already designed a packet structure that I would conform to ideally)

So my primary question: it is worth it to start from a lower level with Asio, or should I try to graft MPI onto what i'm looking for? Further, are there 'skeleton applications' available which use MPI or Asio which would aid development? (Actually I am 100% new to C++.. ;) Or, does it make sense to use them in tandem?

For more perspective, maybe it's worth noting that I already have implemented the bulk of this project in Perl using [Perl Object Environment](https://metacpan.org/module/POE), which itself is just an asynchronous event system with a ton of networking libraries.

Also, if it makes a difference, I would ideally use threads for this. 
Honestly though I have not used Boost at all yet, as I hinted above, so any input is appreciated.

Comment: The greatest downside of MPI is the lack of fault tolerance. It was designed for a completely different purpose, namely High Performance Computing, and works best with fast and reliable networks that WANs are not. You could also take a look at ZeroMQ.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Boost.MPI vs Boost.Asio](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4113026/boost-mpi-vs-boost-asio)

Comment: Indeed, the referred questions are useful, thanks

Answer (score 0):

I should start by saying that I know nothing about Asio, but from the 2 minute scan of the website and the description of your problem, it sounds like while either would probably work for you, Asio might be simpler. MPI is really designed less for general purpose network communication and more for running applications where the set of processes and applications is a little more static. While it provides a client/server style interface if desired, it's not the main focus of the library.

MPI is also more difficult to use if you already have a packet structure designed. MPI is great for abstracting away the need to worry about packets, location of processes, etc. but if you've already taken all of that into account in you application, you have already done the hard work.

There have been at least one other discussion of Asio vs. MPI that you can take a look at ([For distributed applications, which to use, ASIO vs. MPI?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2399019/for-distributed-applications-which-to-use-asio-vs-mpi?rq=1)) to get more opinions too.